# surrender got notified no internet

Tags: lubuntu, internet

I am running lubuntu 18.04.5 lts on a Toshiba Equium A200 and suddenly got a message in top right of screen of no internet. The botom right tool bar icon shows two screens with a X between them. When I click on icon the 'WiFi networks' and 'WiFi is disabled' option is grayed out and the options below VPN are 'enable WiFi' and 'enable networking' are checked. 'Edit connections' takes me to a Ethernet or my WiFi option, then I have to choose a network type, then input said. (Not sure what to do here)
I've contacted my ISP and all is OK their end- other devices work fine.
Can anyone help or advise please?

Comment: Were you using wired or wireless internet when the problem happened?  What *exactly* were you doing when the problem happened?

Comment: I was reading an essay on WordPress. I was on wireless with BT which worked fine up til that point

Comment: Just found a WiFi disable button underneath keyboard so switched to on and all OK now. Sorry for that, I feel quite foolish now

Comment: Resolved, I posted answer for future reference

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.